# 4" Dryer vent duct melt a 2" PVC drain vent pipe?

Tags: dryer, pvc

I'm relocating my washer and dryer and the only way I can get the dry vent hooked up to the dryer is to have it resting against the PVC drain vent pipe. I've done some research and it seems like the PVC melting point is a higher temp than what the dryer vent pipe will get up to. Than again, I'm just carpenter not a plumber. Will this cause any problems in the future or should it be okay? I'd rather not do this but it's the only option I have currently. Any advice is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Dryer vents are hottest at the dryer, they cool down fast away(a foot).  Any chance of getting an air space of 1/8 or 1/4 inch between the two?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I can't get any room at all away from each other. The point that they hit is about 3' of pipe away from the dryer.

Comment: Three feet should be okay for normal dryer operation(lint fires excepted).  Can also see this question for more information.   https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/266541/how-much-clearance-is-needed-around-a-dryer-vent-duct-bc-canada?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for that info

Comment: What diameter is each pipe, and what material is the dryer vent pipe - both salient factors for providing an answer.

Comment: @Trent even the tiniest air gap would make a difference.  Thermal decoupling of some things I've worked with (on a smaller scale) is done by wrapping one in a spiral of fishing line.  I'm not saying that's your solution, bit cable (zip) ties could give you about 1mm (with the latch out of the way.  If that won't fit, the chances of it going together with nothing at all in there are pretty slim

Comment: Get a flat silicone pot holder or double up a silicone baking mat, and just slip it between the duct and pipe.

Comment: I've seen PVC DWV pipe used for dryer venting (after a short segment of flexible duct from the dryer), with no apparent problem. PVC pipe is also used to vent combustion gases from high-efficiency gas-fired appliances. I do not forsee a problem with your situation.